# What properties do functions that converge as (Schwartz) distributions have?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

For definiteness, let's just consider $L^1$ functions. Then any $L^1$ function can be considered as a classical or tempered distribution. In particular, suppose we have a sequence of $L^1$ function $f_n$ and an $L^1$ function $f$ s.t. $f_n \to f$ as distributions (either classical or tempered). In other words,
$$\int (f_n - f)\phi \to 0,$$
for all $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ for some open $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ (for classical distributions) or for all $\phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^n)$ for tempered distributions.

What can we say about other forms of convergence $f_n \to f$, e.g. a.e. pointwise, in measure, in $L^p$, or having a subsequence such that one of those holds? It's easy to see that in general, we can't have convergence in $L^1$, since e.g. $f_n = 1_{[n,n+1]}$ converges to $0$ in the above sense, but not in $L^1$.

Comment: Well, your example also excludes $L^p$, no?

Comment: Yeah of course, though there could be some additional assumptions we put on our functions that give convergence in $L^p$. E.g. dominated convergence theorem puts an additional assumption on pointwise a.e. convergence and gives convergence in $L^1$.

Comment: You are aware that $n\sin(n^2 t)$ converges to $0$ in the sense of distributions ?

Comment: @reuns No, that's interesting though. That brings a new class of counterexamples to the problem, i.e. in $L^p$ convergence, we are integrating over the absolute value, while in distributions, integrals are over the signed functions, so there can be cancellation of the positive and negative parts. I think we can only get interesting results then if we restrict to the positive functions. I'm pretty sure I can show that if $f_n, f$ are positive functions in $L^p$ and dominated by a $L^p$ function, then $T_{f_n} \to T_f$, i.e. convergence as distributions, implies that $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$.